# Alpha value not persisting while saving Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net

Good morning all,

I am making an Image Steganography project for college. 
While hiding data in image. I am writing the "Text Length" which is an Int32 in a pixel. As Int32 is of 4 bytes. I thought I could write it in the 4 bytes of Alpha,Red,Green,Blue, as each color is of 1 byte. 
Then I save the image in bmp format. 
I used single stepping and data get properly distributed and set in the pixel.

The problem arise when I read back the pixel. R,G,B have their value as i had set them. But the alpha is always 255 no matter what it was set.

Code that I am using for distributing Int32 into 4 bytes are

```
byte R, G, B, A;
int colorValue = messageLength;
int first = colorValue & 255;
//R contains bit 0-7 means the least significant 8 bits
R = (byte)first;
colorValue = colorValue - first;
int second = colorValue & 65535;
colorValue = colorValue - second;
second = second >> 8;
//G contains 8-15
G = (byte)second;
int third = colorValue & 16777215;
colorValue = colorValue - third;
third = third >> 16;
//B contains 16-23
B = (byte)third;
colorValue = colorValue >> 24;
//A contains 24-31
A = (byte)colorValue;
pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
bitmap.SetPixel(location.X, location.Y, pixelColor);
```

Code for getting the values back is

```
byte R, G, B, A;
R = pixelColor.R;
G = pixelColor.G;
B = pixelColor.B;
A = pixelColor.A;

messageLength = A;
messageLength = messageLength << 8;
messageLength += B;
messageLength = messageLength << 8;
messageLength += G;
messageLength = messageLength << 8;
messageLength += R;
```

Is there something I am missing. Is it that BMP does not allow alpha value to persist???
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the code that you're using to write and read the bitmap. Can you post that?

Comment: Not sure, hence the comment, but wouldn't you need something such as a `PNG` to hold alpha values?

Comment: Seems it's not possible. Perhaps [use PNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: I just want to confirm that using Bitmap.MakeTransparent() and Bitmap.Save(sFilePath, ImageFormat.Png) can preserve alpha values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that Bitmap doesn't support an alpha value.

Comment: If you click around a bit to where you link, you'll find [_"The high byte in each DWORD is not used"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [_"The Windows API is not capable of generating BMP images with alpha information and very few graphics editing programs are able to preserve transparency when saving images as BMP files."_](https://github.com/thomerow/png2bmp32). So while it technically may be possible to utilize all four bytes in order to store an alpha channel, it cannot be done using .NET's mechanism to save bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The BMP format technically can, but the Bitmap class actually can't. Mistook Bitmap for BMP. My apologies. I've always used PNG in the past when I needed to use alpha values.

Comment: @ChrisMantle but the libraries you linked in in your (now removed) comment **do** allow the user to write the otherwise unused byte. Perfect for hiding information, like OP wants. Unless those files have to be openable and savable by other editors, because those will wipe the hidden data.