# ARGB model - alpha always 255 when saved

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, argb

I have a list of colors and I am making a bitmap from it. Each color has a specific value for A, R, G and B. The problem is that when I save the bitmap and when I load it from the bitmap image file, all values for (A) Alpha are changed automatically to 255.

Here is the code for making the bitmap:

```
private Bitmap PaintImage(List<Color> colors, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
    int colorIndex = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, colors[colorIndex])
            colorIndex += 1;
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Here is the code for saving the bitmap:

```
bitmap.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

**Solution: I fixed the problem by using the PNG format.**

Comment: What is the value of the [`PixelFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat.aspx) of the bitmap?

Comment: The Windows API's used for reading and writing BMP files don't support an alpha value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077947/alpha-value-not-persisting-while-saving-bitmap

Comment: Thanks for this information but is there a solution? Or I have to leave it like that...

Comment: Use another format, for example PNG, or use a different API that does support the alpha byte (as the BMP format does support it).

Comment: The problem is that the PNG format is using compression and the values will be changed (not sure, will check). I making some kind of cryptography.

Comment: PNG compression is lossless.

Comment: Fixed the problem, thanks.